# Same script computes different results on Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, softmax

I am trying to implement [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) but weirdly I am getting two different outputs on MATLAB and on Python:

**MATLAB script:**

```
function sm = softmax(Y)
    e_y = exp(Y - max(Y))
    sm = e_y / sum(e_y)
```

which computes ten times `0.1` as a column vector (correctly because the sum over each column is `1`) if Y is a `10x200` matrix of `501`

Meanwhile this **Python script:**

```
import numpy as np

def softmax(y):
    e_y = np.exp(y - np.max(y))
    return e_y / e_y.sum()

y = np.full((10,200), fill_value=501)
print(softmax(y))
```

computes, on the same input `y`,

```
[[0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
 [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
 [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
 ...
 [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
 [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
 [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]]
```

which is wrong since sum of each column is *not* `1` but it it `0.005`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really intended to do is computing an *element-wise* division instead of a *matrix* division: you need to replace `/` operator with `./` - according to [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html) - in your MATLAB script which was (wrongly) computing a *single* column vector or `0.1`s instead of a *matrix* of `0.1`s, as [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) noticed in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113374/same-script-computes-different-results-on-matlab-and-python/74113722#comment130854910_74113722).

Also, in your Python script you are considering the *whole* matrix `max` element, meanwhile you should consider each column, which represents a *single* prediction, and normalize it. That is:

```
def softmax(y):
    e_y = np.exp(y - np.max(y, axis=0))
    return e_y / np.sum(e_y, axis=0)  # axis = 0
```

You will correctly get a `(10,200)` shaped array/matrix composed as follows:

```
array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       ...,
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]])
```

Further demo:

```
# Allocate a (3,4) matrix composed of 0..11 elements
y = np.asmatrix(np.arange(12)).reshape(3,4)
print(softmax(y))
```

you'll get:

```
matrix([[3.29320439e-04, 3.29320439e-04, 3.29320439e-04, 3.29320439e-04],
        [1.79802867e-02, 1.79802867e-02, 1.79802867e-02, 1.79802867e-02],
        [9.81690393e-01, 9.81690393e-01, 9.81690393e-01, 9.81690393e-01]])
```

Comment: This is partially correct. But the MATLAB `sm = e_y / sum(e_y)` is a *matrix division*. This was likely never intended, but that is what it is. `x = A/b` solves the system of linear equations `x*b = A`. I think the MATLAB code should have used `./` instead of `/`.